# Travel from Budapest to Cluj-Napoca

Tags: public-transport, online-resources, romania, hungary

I need to find a fast way (but for reasonable money) to get by public transport from Budapest (Hungary) to Cluj-Napoca (Romania).

Is there an online service for planning such travel?

Comment: www.rome2rio.com

Comment: Go to www.mav.hu, switch to English, and search for trains, *direct connections*.  There used to be maybe a couple of direct train connections.  "Corona" arrives at night, used to be between 1 AM and 2 AM.  These trains typically leave from Budapest Eastern station (Budapest Keleti pályaudvar).  I recommend trains over buses unless you can put up with discomfort.  I do *not* recommend that you transfer trains unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Alternatively, plan for a *single* transfer in Püspökladány (search for Püspökladány - Cluj), which gives you one additional option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you have a look at [rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Budapest/Cluj-Napoca) which find both bus and train connections between those two cities.

Trains seem to go every two hours, take 7h of total traveling time and cost €26, changing twice in Püspökladany and Biharkeresztes.

Buses are direct either from Budapest Nepliget bus station (easily reachable by metro from anywhere in Budapest) or from Budapest airport (reachable by bus+metro from Budapest city) taking about 7h and going four or five times daily. Bus operator in both cases is the Romanian [presidenttour.ro](http://www.presidenttour.ro/en) and cost seems to be around €20.

Comment: I've made this trip from Budapest airport to Cluj-Napoca two years ago, and the vehicles are more of like large vans than actual buses, so the trip through mountainous Transylvania might not be very comfortable -- but it's quite beautiful.

Comment: I *very strongly* doubt that trains go every 2 hours, this must be some artefact of how that site presents the connections, but it is not realistic, and anyone reading this should not rely on this information (otherwise you may end up with lots of transfers and no reduction in travel/arrival time).  There is certainly one direct international train and maybe one more with a single transfer, which gives only two *reasonable* options per day.  I've made this trip several times and I could research a reasonable travel plan, but the question is closed now.

Comment: well, you may doubt it - but what rome2rio suggests doesn't seem too far off, seeing that the [mav website](http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll/xslvzs/index?language=2) finds seven (six with 1 or less changes) connections a day that are around the 8h duration mark and several more that take longer..

Answer (score 2):

You can fly to Targu Mures with Wizzair (can be as low as 5990 HUF around 20 EUR, I see that for sep 30 https://wizzair.com/en-GB/TimeTable/Budapest?arrivalIATA=TGM) and take the bus (25 lei around 5.7 EUR) from Targu Mures to Cluj. Beats sitting on a bus for seven hours.

Comment: It would be the best answer on my question but this flight has too bad schedule, but +1 anyway!